# Dual formula in propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

There's something I don't understand in my course on propositional logic.

In the case of x being a variable, the definition of its dual is *x* = x*. Right.

However, further in the course, there's a corollary stating : *In propositional logic, if a formula is valid, its dual is contradictory*.

How can this be true if x* = x ?

Does it even make sense to talk about the truth value of a variable ?

I'm a little bit confused...

Comment: A single prop variable can never be *valid* nor *contradictory*; to the formula $p$ you can **always** assign the truth-vale **t** (and thus it cannot be contradictory) or the truth-value **f** (and thus it cannot be a tautology).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Alright, that's perfectly clear now, thank you :)

Comment: @Chiliagon Are you following a book or course notes? Are the courses notes freely available?

Comment: @GitGud The course slides can be found here : [link](http://www-verimag.imag.fr/~monin/EnseignementPublic/L2/INF242/Slides/Full/) (This directory is updated every week)

Comment: @Chiliagon Judging from [theorem 1.5.7](http://www-verimag.imag.fr/~monin/EnseignementPublic/L2/INF242/Slides/Full/cours2_En.pdf), I suppose you already know that any formula is equivalent to a formula in CNF or DNF. So it suffices to prove the corollary for formulas in CNF or DNF.